# Non-whitespace sensitive transpiler that offers string interpolation / list comprehensions / dictionary iteration that compiles to ES5

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a transpiler that produces javascript that is directly runnable in a browser, that interops cleanly with javascript, without additional runtime requirements. At the very least I'm looking for a language that does list comprehensions, string interpolatino and dictionary iteration; more is welcome.

I've tried nearly all options listed on https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js, and I've spent about two weeks googling, but all that I've found have some combination of these problems:

- Whitespace-sensitive block scoping (coffeescript et al)
- Not actively maintained
- Incomplete/experimental
- Interop is clunky
- Additional runtime needs to be loaded for the generated JS to work (traceur for example)

Initially coffeescript ticked all the boxes, but I don't like its var scoping, and personally I think the siginificant whitespace works everywhere except for closures, which I happen to use a lot. I realize this is a matter of preference, but my preference goes the other way. I'm open to pretty much any other syntax -- after trying to like coffeescript for a few weeks, I finally tried to get up to speed with lisp, but could not find one of those either that didn't hit on one of the above problems.